# Error while installing deepdish

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, caffe, lmdb

I'm trying to create an LMDB database file to be used with Caffe according to [this](http://deepdish.io/) tutorial on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine using Anaconda Python 2.7.9. However, when I do `pip install deepdish`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Collecting deepdish
  Using cached deepdish-0.1.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qKwOBx/deepdish/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qKwOBx/deepdish
```

Any ideas why this error might be occurring and how to go about correcting it? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Author here. This bug has been resolved in recent versions. Sorry about this bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't seem to figure out why the error occurred, but after struggling for a while, I did the following and it seemed to work:

1. Download the zip file from Github.
2. Unzip the file after navigating to the directory where you've downloaded the file using the command `unzip deepdish-master.zip`.
3. Navigate to the unzipped folder: `cd deepdish-master`.
4. Make the setup.py file executable: `chmod +x setup.py`.
5. Run the file with the 'install' option: `./setup.py install`.
6. If you want, you may delete the zip folder and the unzipped folder.

Now if you go into the python environment in the terminal and do `import deepdish as dd`, it works like a charm!